# Oracle not using indexes if queried in wrong order

Tags: oracle, indexing

I have tried to find similar issue, but didn't find it. If this is a duplicate, please point me to  correct topic.

Oracle version 19 Standard Edition 2, version 19.3.

I have a table BOOKING.
Some of the columns:

| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | NULLABLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | NUMBER(38,0) | No |
| CLASSID | NUMBER(5,0) | Yes |
| PARENTFOREIGNKEY | NUMBER(38,0) | Yes |
| BOOKINGNO | NUMBER(4,0) | Yes |

It has following indexes (that are important for this question):

| INDEX_NAME | UNIQUENESS | STATUS | INDEX_TYPE | COLUMNS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BOOKING | UNIQUE | VALID | NORMAL | ID |
| BOOKING_511_2 | NONUNIQUE | VALID | NORMAL | PARENTFOREIGNKEY, CLASSID, ID |

executing the query
`SELECT * FROM BOOKING WHERE (CLASSID=511) AND PARENTFOREIGNKEY=31647961 ORDER BY BOOKINGNO;`
takes around 40-45 seconds.
whereas
`SELECT * FROM BOOKING WHERE PARENTFOREIGNKEY=31647961 AND (CLASSID=511)  ORDER BY BOOKINGNO;`
takes only around 0.013 second.

It is obvious that first query is not using indexes, where the second on is. Explain plans are identical.

```
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                           |     4 |   648 |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                       |                           |     4 |   648 |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| BOOKING     |     4 |   648 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | BOOKING_511_2 |     4 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - access("PARENTFOREIGNKEY"=31647961 AND "CLASSID"=511)
```

Can someone tell me what is going on? Why aren't both queries equivalent in the execution?

Thank you,
GG

EDIT:
Explain plans (`SELECT * FROM TABLE(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'BASIC +PREDICATE'));`):

```
EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT:
------------------------
SELECT * FROM BOOKING WHERE (CLASSID=:"SYS_B_0") AND 
PARENTFOREIGNKEY=:"SYS_B_1" ORDER BY BOOKINGNO
 
Plan hash value: 1769702959
 
----------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name                  |
----------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |                       |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY     |                       |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| BOOKING               |
----------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter(("PARENTFOREIGNKEY"=:SYS_B_1 AND "CLASSID"=:SYS_B_0))
```

"Fast" query:

```
EXPLAINED SQL STATEMENT:
------------------------
SELECT * FROM BOOKING WHERE PARENTFOREIGNKEY=:"SYS_B_0" 
AND (CLASSID=:"SYS_B_1")  ORDER BY BOOKINGNO
 
Plan hash value: 3357352015
 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name                      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                           |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                       |                           |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| BOOKING                   |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | BOOKING_511_2             |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - access("PARENTFOREIGNKEY"=:SYS_B_0 AND "CLASSID"=:SYS_B_1)
```

Comment: Please, provide both actual execution plans with `dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => 'BASIC +PREDICATE)` executed right after the statement execution. I cannot reproduce your behaviour in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b174fee798ac53bb01c3a8c4f68ab33e)

Comment: So the first query ran slowly and the second ran quickly. If you run the first query again is it slow again, consistently?

Comment: @pmdba: yes, the behaviour is consistent. so, slow response after slow response, and fast after fast (and fast after slow...all combinations have been tried and repeated)

Comment: @GoranGerlič Generate the execution plans again, but this time using `SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);`. The "BASIC" format won't display the "Note" section, which can be critical for debugging plan issues. In general, the predicate order does not matter. The most common exception, if a DBA created a SQL Profile that only works for one specific SQL_ID, will be explained in the "Note" section.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The order of columns in your search predicate needs to match the order of the columns in the index. From "[How to Create and Use Indexes in Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-and-use-indexes-in-oracle-database)":

> Oracle Database reads an index starting with its leftmost (“first”)
> column. Then it goes onto the second, third, etc. So if you have an
> index on:
>
> ```
> create index i on tab ( col1, col2, col3 );
> ```
>
> And your where clause is:
>
> ```
> where col3 = 'value'
> ```
>
> To use the index the database either has to
> wade through all the values in col1 and col2. Or, more likely, read
> the whole thing to find those matching your conditions.

In your case, the problem is the third column in your index. If the index were only on the `classid` and `parentforeignkey` columns then the order of the predicates wouldn't make any difference. With the addition of the `id` column to the index and the change in order of the predicates, the optimizer determines that it is easier to just scan the entire table once than to use the index, which it would have to scan twice in its entirety. There are examples of this in the article which are to lengthy to duplicate here.

Comment: The quote, whilst accurate, doesn't equate exactly to what the OP is doing. The OP is querying using `col1` and `col2`, just not in that order. I'm not saying your wrong, just that I don't think the quote proves that you're correct. I'm somewhat surprised the CBO isn't working this out...

Comment: @pmdba: true, we found that out. What is intriguing about this is, that while this is happening for some Oracle users, for some users this is not the case. And this is the same Oracle server. And we did not observe this behaviour for years now. It started this month only.
We did change our code generation that queries now match index order.

Comment: @pmdba 
another thing that was discovered: how Oracle uses this indexes depends on Oracle installation. we have several servers, each of them several users (many customers). One server "decided" not to use indexes if the query is not in correct order. Other servers use indexes even if query is in different order. What makes this difference is still unknown.

Comment: @Ben the optimizer was having issues because of the 3rd column in the index. There's an example in the article of that exact scenario. I thought it too length to copy the whole thing, which is why i mentioned it in my answer. If not for the 3rd column in the index, then the order of the columns in the search predicate wouldn't matter. The third column, unused in the predicate, makes it more expensive to use the index if the predicate order is off.

Comment: @pmdba - The order might matter in the index creation DDL or in the `ORDER BY` clause, but the order of predicates in the query should almost never matter. There must be something weird going on here, like there's a plan management feature that only works for a specific SQL_ID.
@GoranGerlič - You shouldn't have to change your code generation to match index order. Instead, look for environment differences in the full execution plans, and in data dictionary views like DBA_SQL_PROFILES, DBA_OUTLINES, and DBA_REWRITE_EQUIVALENCES.