# Oracle performance lowered by using parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, parentheses

I've read this: [Parenthesis() and SQL Query Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525744/parenthesis-and-sql-query-performance)

I have posted this: [Oracle not using indexes if queried in wrong order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68888794/oracle-not-using-indexes-if-queried-in-wrong-order)

What we are experiencing right now is beyond my understanding, and I am asking for explanation.

Query:
`SELECT * FROM PREMIUMACCOUNTBOOKING p WHERE PARENTFOREIGNKEY = 499699430 AND CLASSID = 511 ORDER BY BOOKINGNO;`

lasts 3 ms.

Explanation plan:

```
Plan hash value: 3357352015
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                           |     4 |   632 |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                       |                           |     4 |   632 |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| PREMIUMACCOUNTBOOKING     |     4 |   632 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | PREMIUMACCOUNTBOOKI_511_2 |     4 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - access("PARENTFOREIGNKEY"=499699430 AND "CLASSID"=511)
```

Now, query `SELECT * FROM PREMIUMACCOUNTBOOKING WHERE PARENTFOREIGNKEY=499699430 AND (CLASSID=511) ORDER BY BOOKINGNO;`
lasts 40 seconds! Repeatedly. No improvement even after several executions.

Explanation plan:

```
Plan hash value: 3357352015
 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                           |     4 |   632 |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                       |                           |     4 |   632 |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| PREMIUMACCOUNTBOOKING     |     4 |   632 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | PREMIUMACCOUNTBOOKI_511_2 |     4 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   3 - access("PARENTFOREIGNKEY"=499699430 AND "CLASSID"=511)
```

I do not see any difference, except in actual execution time.

What can I do to identify the reason for this behaviour?

Thank you,
GG

Comment: And does the query without () still run for 3ms?

Comment: Hi @Gnqz, yes, this was the behaviour. We had to restart the server. Physically. This behaviour is at the moment not observed.